# SonarLint on Intellij: Unsupported class file major version 61 while using Java 11

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint

I was trying to connect SonarLint to my project and when I try to analyze any file, the following error return:

```
Unable to create symbol table for : /Users/Documents/RoutingTest.java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:176)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:158)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:146)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.BytecodeCompleter.loadClass(BytecodeCompleter.java:244)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.Symbols.<init>(Symbols.java:176)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.SemanticModel.createFor(SemanticModel.java:60)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:109)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:96)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:68)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanTests(JavaSquid.java:122)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:111)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:93)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.analyzer.sensor.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:80)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.analyzer.sensor.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:71)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.analysis.AnalysisContainer.doAfterStart(AnalysisContainer.java:132)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:126)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:111)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.storage.StorageAnalyzer.analyze(StorageAnalyzer.java:75)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.storage.StorageContainerHandler.analyze(StorageContainerHandler.java:83)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.lambda$analyze$0(ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.java:153)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.withReadLock(ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.java:352)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.withReadLock(ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.java:342)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.analyze(ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.java:150)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.core.ConnectedSonarLintFacade.analyze(ConnectedSonarLintFacade.java:73)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.core.SonarLintFacade.startAnalysis(SonarLintFacade.java:62)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.analysis.SonarLintAnalyzer.analyzeModule(SonarLintAnalyzer.java:89)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.analysis.SonarLintTask.analyzePerModule(SonarLintTask.java:351)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.analysis.SonarLintTask.run(SonarLintTask.java:139)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.analysis.SonarLintUserTask.run(SonarLintUserTask.java:38)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.startTask(CoreProgressManager.java:442)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.startTask(ProgressManagerImpl.java:114)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsynchronously$5(CoreProgressManager.java:493)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:252)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:188)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$12(CoreProgressManager.java:608)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:683)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:639)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:607)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:175)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:252)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

It seems to be something about jdk, but i'm already using java 11. I have already uninstall all java versions and install just java 11 but still having the same error.

I add the Intellij project structure:
[image]

Also, I'm using version 4.16.0 of SonarLint (I can not update it because of the SonarQube). It's a maven project with the following version:

```
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Maven home: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.8.6/libexec
Java version: 11.0.16, vendor: Amazon.com Inc., runtime: /Users/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.16-amzn
Default locale: en_ES, platform encoding: UTF-8
```

Also I have tried to see which version of java has my compiler use to generate the .class of one file in which the error occurs and the version is 55, java 11.

Comment: Please share project structure in IntelliJ IDEA (like https://i.imgur.com/6FAw0Ih.png). What Java version is set there?

Comment: It seems your compiled java classes are not compatible with sonar lint, what is the version of sonar lint you are using?

Comment: [Class file version 61](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) is Java 17. It looks like you have compiled your class files using JDK 17, and not JDK 11 despite you saying you've configured that. Is it a Maven or Gradle project? Is Maven or Gradle configured to use JDK 11 and not JDK 17? You'll have to dig deeper into why your code is compiled with JDK 17.